# How do I track a crash without any error output with an external accessory attached?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, crash, external-accessory

I'm currently developing an app that controls an external accessory, so I can't debug the app with xcode while testing most features. I'm already saving log output to a file on the device, but I just starting seeing an unexpected crash that doesn't leave any error output.

Is there any way to get more information from the crash without having access to a stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace is one of the best sources of information about a crash that you can get. What is the problem with the crash report?

Comment: The problem is that there isn't one. Every other crash I've had on this project has posted something to the device log. This crash doesn't post any information at all, and I can't track it down with xcode since it only happens when an external accessory is connected to the lightning connector on the device.

Comment: If there is a crash, then there should be a report. I'd say it is highly unlikely that there is an actual crash without a report. Maybe there is not crash after all? You could also integrate a 3rd party crash reporting SDK or use something like [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) to stream log data to a Mac client so you can follow what your app is doing. But you'd need to add log statements in your code.

Comment: I'm just not sure why it would force quit whenever it receives a message from the accessory if it weren't crashing. I'll give your suggestions a try, though.

Comment: Turns out it was a crash after all. Thanks for your suggestion. Using a 3rd party SDK, (Crittercism), helped me nail it down.